# Find $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\tan x-\tan a}{\ln x-\ln a}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\tan x-\tan a}{\ln x-\ln a}$$ Solve that limit while $a$ is unknown.

I have tried applying l’Hopital rule however it didn’t seem to work. I have tried simplifying it but I’m still very confused on how are you able to take a limit to an unknown variable.

Any explanation is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to MSE. Your post will be better received if you have shown us what you have tried, or what your motivation behind the question is!

Comment: I have tried applying l’Hopital rule, however no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h$ be small. Then $$\tan(a+h) - \tan(a)=\sec^2(a)\cdot h + o(h)$$ and $$\ln(a+h) - \ln(a) = \ln \left(1+\frac{h}{a}\right) = \frac{h}{a}+o(h)$$
hence $$f(a+h) = \frac{\sec^2(a)\cdot h + o(h)}{h/a + o(h)}=a\sec^2(a) +o(1)$$
so the desired limit is $$a\sec^2(a)$$

Comment: Great. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$$\frac{\tan(x)-\tan(a)}{\ln(x)-\ln(a)}=\frac{\tan(x)-\tan(a)}{x-a}\frac{1}{\frac{\ln(x)-\ln(a)}{x-a}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{\tan x-\tan a}{\ln x-\ln a}=\dfrac{\sin(x-a)}{\cos x\cos a\ln\left(1+\dfrac{x-a}a\right)}$$

$$=\dfrac1{\cos x\cos a}\cdot\dfrac{\sin(x-a)}{x-a}\cdot\dfrac1{ \dfrac{a\cdot\ln\left(1+\dfrac{x-a}a\right)}{\dfrac{x-a}a}}$$

Now use $\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\sin h}h=1$ and $\lim_{k\to0}\dfrac{\ln(1+k)}k=1$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use L'Hopital rule:
$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\tan x-\tan a}{\ln x-\ln a}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{1+\tan^2 x}{\frac1x}$$